# Calling file as owner inside of correct directory but not found

Tags: unix, permissions

I would really appreciate some help here, this has been driving me crazy for a week or so now. I'm trying to run a script, i've done this multiple times across other boxes we use however this one is not playing ball. I'm not sure what the problem is...

I've searched only for P1_Lymm_Healthcheck and it's returned the full filename, whilst saying it cannot find it, i've chmodded the file 777 and am trying to run from both control-m and also directly from the box itself, as the user that owns the file.

[image: searching for only P1_Lymm_Healthcheck*]

Thanks in advance to anyone who does help me out - i'm quite new to unix!

Comment: run `./P1_Lymm_Healthcheck_Script`.

Comment: Hi there - i appreciate your help, unfortunately after running this, same thing is still happening, i'm at a loss as to what the issue could be! "ksh: ./P1_Lymm_Healthcheck_Script:  not found
"

Comment: Hi all - the fix to this problem was the following: There were a bunch of ^M's at the end of each line - after some fact finding, it seems it had something to do with !/bin/ksh or the lack there-of as i had accidentally commented this out.

Hopefully this will help people in the future if they have the same issue! :)